# To pinch or to grab someone's face?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> "She ***pinched*** my face. That hurt."
>
> "She ***grabbed*** my face. That hurt"

What word is more suitable for the action illustrated in the image below?

[image]

Comment: Not what the picture shows, but for comparison you might get away with "she grabbed my cheek" if she then dragged you to the corner by the cheek. [Grab](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/grab) implies seizing or taking control of something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd call that a pinch. You can be more specific and say "she pinched his *cheek*", which means exactly what's shown in the picture.

Answer (score 2):

For me, at least, 'she pinched my face' means she grabbed a part of the face, whereas 'she grabbed my face' implies that the entirety of the face was grabbed.  While grabbing the entirety of someone's face is possible, it's not the action being depicted above.  That's definitely a pinch!